# if value not in self._dict: TypeError: unhashable type: 'StyleProxy' in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am using below code for updating an excel (.xlsm) file and copying some values from it to some other positions in the same file.Here i am using two functions for copying and pasting some required range of cells from one position to another and want to copy the cells with complete font and boundary

my code looks like-

```
wb=load_workbook('Excel.xlsm',read_only=False,keep_vba=True)
ws=wb['K0 Reg Patch Util']
def copyRange(startCol,startRow,endCol,endRow,sheet):
    rangeSelected=[]
    fontSelected=[]
    borderSelected=[]
    for i in range(startRow,endRow+1,1):
       rowSelected=[]
       font=[]
       border=[]
       for j in range(startCol,endCol+1,1):
           rowSelected.append(sheet.cell(row=i,column=j).value)
           font.append(sheet.cell(row=i,column=j).font)
           border.append(sheet.cell(row=i,column=j).border)
           rangeSelected.append(rowSelected)
           fontSelected.append(font)
           borderSelected.append(border)
           return rangeSelected,fontSelected,borderSelected
def pasteRange(startCol,startRow,endCol,endRow,sheet,copiedData,fontData,borderData):
countRow=0
  for i in range(startRow,endRow+1,1):
      countCol=0
      for j in range(startCol,endCol+1,1):
          sheet.cell(row=i,column=j).value=copiedData[countRow][countCol]
          sheet.cell(row=i,column=j).font=fontData[countRow][countCol]
          sheet.cell(row=i,column=j).value=borderData[countRow][countCol]
          countCol+=1
      countRow+=1
      copiedData=[]
      fontData=[]
      borderData=[]
copiedData,fontData,borderData=copyRange(2,56,4,66,ws)
startC=ws.max_column+1
endC=startC+2
startR=3
endR=13
pasteRange(startC,startR,endC,endR,ws,copiedData,fontData,borderData)
wb.save('Excel.xlsm')
```

After this when i am running the program i am getting error as-

> File "ReadExcel.py", line 91, in 
>   **pasteRange(startC,startR,endC,endR,ws,copiedData,fontData,borderData)**
>   File "ReadExcel.py", line 73, in pasteRange
>   **sheet.cell(row=i,column=j).font=fontData[countRow][countCol]**
>    File > "/nfs/sc/proj/skx/skx_val356/rsingh/Patch_Proj/Patch_Project_Files/GUI/VGUI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/styles/styleable.py", line 24, in __set__
>       setattr(instance._style, self.key, coll.add(value))
>     File "/nfs/sc/proj/skx/skx_val356/rsingh/Patch_Proj/Patch_Project_Files  /GUI/VGUI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/utils/indexed_list.py", line 48, in add
>       self.append(value)
>     File "/nfs/sc/proj/skx/skx_val356/rsingh/Patch_Proj/Patch_Project_Files/GUI/VGUI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/**openpyxl/utils/indexed_list.py**", line 43, in append
>
> if value not in self._dict:
>   **TypeError: unhashable type: 'StyleProxy'**

can somebody please point me how to remove this error and what mistake i am doing.I have even added a hash function in proxy.py as suggested by some post. 
Please resolve this error

Comment: Edit your code in the Question, you have indentations errors.

Comment: edited the code as per the suggestions-@stovfl

Comment: Can't really read the code. I suggest you use zip over the two ranges and please use openpyx's idioms.

Answer (score 2):

> **Question:  how to remove this error and what mistake i am doing**

You have to `copy` style attributes.
Add and replace the following lines:

```
from copy import copy
...
font.append(copy(sheet.cell(row=i, column=j).font))
...
border.append(copy(sheet.cell(row=i, column=j).border))
```

The second `.value=borderData...` is a typo, this should read:

```
sheet.cell(row=i,column=j).border=borderData[countRow][countCol]
```

It's likely you will get the following Error:

> IndexError: list index out of range

Because your `...Data` lists does not have the same dimension as used in `pasteRange`.
The reason, this line has faulty indentation:

```
return rangeSelected, fontSelected, borderSelected
```

You return after the first cycle in the `for` loop!

---

Consider to redesign your code to a simpler approach.
Instead of first copying **all data** into a **list of list**, copy **direct** from `cell` to `cell`.